# Are Infinite Types (aka Recursive Types) not possible in F#?

Tags: f#, types, type-inference

I was chatting with [Sadek Drobi](http://sadekdrobi.com/) on twitter when be brought up that F# didn't seem to support Infinite Types.  It turns out that in C# you can do something along these lines:

```
delegate RecDelegate<T> RecDelegate<T>(T x);
```

However, after some experimentation on both our parts, we determined that the same in F# seems impossible both implicit and explicitly.

**Explicit:**

```
type 'a specialF = 'a->specialF<'a>
```

> error FS0191: This type definition
>   involves an immediate cyclic reference
>   through an abbreviation, struct field
>   or inheritance relation.

**Implicit:**

```
let rec specialF (x: 'a) = specialF
```

> Type mismatch. Expecting a    'b but
>   given a   'a -> 'b. The resulting type
>   would be infinite when unifying ''b'
>   and ''a -> 'b'.

Of course, these are intentionally simple samples.

I was wondering if I am somehow mistaken. Perhaps I missed some type of necessary annotation?

Comment: Is there a practical application here, or was the question just a result of investigating for fun?

Comment: As far as I understand, there are no practical referentially transparent applications. However, one example would be that with some kind of closed-over mutable state this can be useful for repeated applications. ex: add(1)(2)(3)(4) -- where any number of applications can be done.

Comment: Here's an OCaml program I wrote that uses this feature to avoid a level of indirection using rectypes. http://www.ffconsultancy.com/languages/ray_tracer/code/1/ray.ml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also do something like

```
type 'a RecType = RecType of ('a -> 'a RecType)
```

to create a named type through which to perform the recursion.  Now this works:

```
let rec specialF = RecType (fun _ -> specialF)
```

Comment: I'd also be interested if the more general version works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253374/explicit-type-recursion-in-f

Answer (score 6):

```
type d<'T> = delegate of 'T -> d<'T>  //'
let del : d<int> = null
let anotherDel = del.Invoke(1).Invoke(2).Invoke(3)
```

I think you need a named type that is representable directly in CLI to break the recursion, so in F# this means you need an actual delegate type as well.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive record types should work as well.

```
type A = { A : A }
let rec a : A = { A = a }
```

I'd be interested in a practical application. Or even an impractical one :)