# Explicit type recursion in F#

Tags: f#, recursion, type-systems

*Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228644/are-infinite-types-aka-recursive-types-not-possible-in-f):*

**Is explicit type recursion possible in F#?**

```
type 'a Mu = In of 'a Mu 'a

let unIn (In x) = x
```

This code unfortunatly gives "Type parameter cannot be used as type constructor.

*Remarks: This construct is used in the paper [Functional Programming with Overloading and Higher-Order Polymorphism](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/springschool.html), for example.*

Example of usage (taken from [here](http://blog.plover.com/prog/springschool95-2.html)):

```
type ('a, 'b) ListX =
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'a * 'b

type 'a List = ListX Mu
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Specifically, generics in F# have the same limitation as the CLR, namely a <T> or an <'a> must have kind " * ".  This same limitation is what means you cannot author "type classes" directly in F#, since e.g. "Monad m" would take a higher-kinded argument 'm' (e.g. "* -> *", where e.g. 'list' and 'option' could be instances, those each themselves being generic type constructors), but this is not allowed.

Comment: Haskell type classes work on things of kind `*` too, and in fact classes on higher-kinded types were originally called 'constructor classes', though the distinction is mostly ignored now.