# How can I express a type in F# that optionally recurses on itself (infinitely)

Tags: recursion, f#, types, graphviz, fparsec

As a learning exercise I am trying to implment a parser for the graphviz dot language ([The DOT language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language)) using the functional parser library fparsec ([FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/)). The language describes graphs.

Looking at the language definition I was compelled to write down the following definition:

```
let rec pstmt_list = opt(pstmt .>> opt(pchar ';') >>. opt pstmt_list)
```

Where `pstmt` and `pchar ';'` are parsers, `.>>` and `>>.` combine an occurence of the left parser with an occurence of the right parser, and `opt` parsers an optional occurrence of its argument parser as an option value. However this definition does not work complaining "... the resulting type would be infinite ...".

This example is probably most easily understood by taking a look at the DOT language linked above.

I am aware of the following seemingly linked questions:

- [Are Infinite Types (aka Recursive Types) not possible in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228644/are-infinite-types-aka-recursive-types-not-possible-in-f)
- [Haskell to F# - declare a recursive types in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917091/haskell-to-f-declare-a-recursive-types-in-f)

But my F# knowledge may not be sufficient to translate them yet, if they apply here at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FParsec provides special combinators for parsing sequences. Normally you should prefer these combinators to reimplementing them with a recursive function. You can find an overview of the available combinators for parsing sequences here: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/parser-overview.html#parsing-sequences

In this example `pstmt_list` is a sequence of statements separated and optionally ended by semicolons, so you could easily define the parser as

```
let pstmt_list = sepEndBy pstmt (pstring ";")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `pstmt_list` parser produces some values of some type, but when you use it in the definition, you wrap the values of this type with additional `option` type (using the `opt` combinator).

The F# compiler thinks that the type of the values returned by the parser e.g. `'a` should be the same as the wrapped type `option 'a` (which is, of course, not possible).

Anyway, I don't think that this is quite what you need to do - the `.>>` combinator creates a parser that returns the result of the second argument, which means that you'll be ignoring all the results of `pstmt` parsed so far.

I think you probably need something like this:

```
let rec pstmt_list : Parser<int list, unit> = 
  parse.Delay(fun () ->
    opt(pstmt .>> pchar ';') .>>. opt pstmt_list
    |>> (function Some(prev), Some(rest) -> prev::rest
                | Some(prev), _ -> [prev]
                | _, Some(rest) -> rest
                | _ -> [] ))
```

The additional use of `Delay` is to avoid declaring a value that refers directly to itself.

Comment: The `.>>` combinator actually returns the result of the *left* parser (i.e. the result of the first argument parser). The point points to the parser whose result is returned.

Comment: @Stephan - You're right (of course :-)). When I wrote that, I was actually thinking about the `>>.` operator (used later in the parser).

Comment: Thanks very much your answer, I think the other answer is proper one of this question, but I'm personally more interested in understanding your one and making it work. I replaced `Parser<int list, unit>` with `Parser<int list, unit>` to make it compile, but I get a stack overflow exception. Could you explain how the Delay works and suggest why the recursion doesn't terminate?